# Is there a place to put Javascript code that you would like to run the first time a user downloads/opens your chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a chrome extension and want to store information if the user has logged in. The way I check that is by running a chrome.storage.get on the field which states if they are logged in. However, when users download the app for the first time, there is no value stored there and the chrome.storage.get returns an error.

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize [`onInstalled`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onInstalled) method from chrome.runtime API:

> Fired when the extension is first installed, when the extension is updated to a new version, and when Chrome is updated to a new version.

Example:

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function(reason) {
    if (reason === 'install') {
        // Your init code
    }
});
```

The `reason` can be also equal to `"update"`. That allows you to run code when your extension just was updated.